# A Laplace Transform Involving the Complementary Error Function

Tags: integration, laplace-transform

I'm trying to evaluate a Laplace transform that is equivalent to the following integral. According to Wolfram Alpha, it evaluates to

$$I = \int_0^\infty {\operatorname{erfc}\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}\right)e^{-st}}\mathrm dt = \frac{e^{-2a\sqrt{s}}}{s}$$

for positive 'a' and 's'. These assumptions are valid for my application. My approach so far has been to integrate by parts and then introduce the variable substitutions $u=\sqrt{t}$, $v=\frac{\sqrt{s}u^2 + a}{u}$, $w=v^2$, and $x=w-2a\sqrt{s}$ to achieve the following form:

$$I = \frac{2a}{s\sqrt{\pi s}} \int_0^\infty \frac{e^{-x}}{\sqrt{x^2 - 4a^2s}}\mathrm dx$$

At this point, Wolfram Alpha says that the integrand has no elementary antiderivative and exceeds standard computation time trying to evaluate the definite integral. I'm not very experienced using methods involving complex variables but since the integrand is not real-valued for $\lvert x\rvert<2a\sqrt{s}$ I suspect that is what's needed. How should I proceed?

Comment: Integrate by parts and use master theorem.

Comment: @LaxmiNarayanBhandari Are you suggesting that I IBP the original integral or the second one?  I'm not familiar with the Master Theorem, is this what you're talking about: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Glasser%27s_master_theorem?

Comment: IBP on the original integral and use the Cauchy–Schlömilch transformation.

Comment: Still need help?

Comment: I see where you're coming from with the Cauchy-Schlömilch transformation; that's a clever technique.  However, I'm struggling to put the integrand in the appropriate form.  Doing IBP like you suggested and then applying a substitution $u=t^2$, I find the following integral:$$\int_0^\infty u e^{-\left(\sqrt{s}u-\frac{a}{u}\right)^2}du.$$  Since there is a leading 'u' in front of the exponential part, I'm not sure how to apply Cauchy-Schlömilch.

Comment: Probably it's more complicated than I thought. I will try to post an answer later if I manage to solve the integral.

Comment: Thanks!  Also, the substitution I described in my previous comment should be $u = \sqrt{t}$, not $u = t^2$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ok, I managed to evaluate the integral.

Let's call our integral $I(s,a)$. We start by integrating by parts with $u=e^{-st}$. $\DeclareMathOperator\erf{erf}$.

$$\begin{align}I(s,a) &= \left.-\frac1se^{-st}\erf\Big(\frac a{\sqrt t}\Big)\right|_0^\infty -\int_0^\infty -\frac1se^{-st}\cdot \frac{-a}{\sqrt\pi t^{3/2}}\exp\Big(-\frac{a^2}t\Big)\,\mathrm dt \\ &= \frac1s-\frac a{s\sqrt\pi} \int_0^\infty \exp\Big(-st-\frac{a^2}t\Big)\frac{\mathrm dt}{t^{3/2}} \end{align}$$

Now, we substitute $t=\frac1{u^2}$. As the integrand is even,

$$\begin{align}I(s,a) &=\frac1s-\frac a{s\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\Big(-a^2u^2-\frac s{u^2}\Big) \,\mathrm du \\ &= \frac1s-\frac {ae^{-2a\sqrt s}}{s\sqrt\pi}\int_{-\infty}^\infty \exp\Big(-a^2\Big(u-\frac{\sqrt s}{au}\Big)^2\Big)\,\mathrm du\end{align}$$

Now using the Master Theorem,
$$\begin{align} I(s,a) &= \frac1s-\frac {ae^{-a\sqrt s}}{s\sqrt\pi}\underbrace{\int_{-\infty}^\infty e^{-a^2u^2}\,\mathrm du }_{=\frac{\sqrt\pi}a}\\I(s,a) &= \frac{1-e^{-2a\sqrt s}}s \end{align}$$

For sanity check, $I(10,5) = \frac{1-e^{-10\sqrt{10}}}{10}$, which is confirmed by Wolfram|Alpha.
[image]
Now noting that $\text{erfc}(x)=1-\erf(x)$ and $\int_0^\infty e^{-st}\, dt=\frac1s$, we get

$$\int_0^\infty\text{erfc}\Big(\frac a{\sqrt t}\Big)e^{-st}\,\mathrm dt =\frac{e^{-2a\sqrt s}}s $$

Comment: Looks like I neglected to apply the chain rule when evaluating $\frac{d}{dt}erfc\left(\frac{a}{\sqrt{t}}\right)$.  Your answer looks correct to me, except that you used the error function instead of the complementary error function.  If you like, I can edit your answer so it solves the correct problem (or if you prefer, feel free to edit it yourself), and then I will accept your answer.  Again, thanks for suggesting the Cauchy-Schlömilch transformation.  I think it will be useful on some related problems I'm working on!

Comment: @Chris Done. Ok now?

Comment: That looks much better!